# Calling psexec from REST forces it to run twice

Tags: rest, psexec

I have a REST service that has a POST method that executes a `psexec` command that starts different processes (depending on POST data) on remote desktop, and waits for them to terminate (`psexec` is being run without `-d` flag). If the process takes more than 5 min to run (the one I am facing an issue with takes around 5 min), `psexec` command is being executed a second time, so my process is being started twice, the previous instance of it is killed as I start it from a `cmd.exe` instance and a new instance runs. If I run `psexec` command with a `-d` flag that does not wait for a process to terminate, the process is being run correctly, only one time. What is causing this problem? Is it `psexec` command or an issue with a REST service (REST is written in Node.js using Express). This only happens if I call the REST service from a web interface (browser), if I call it from a server directly, it is being run correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `psexec`, I was using [`child_process` module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and its [`exec` function](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) that

> spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell.

It has `timeout` option that defaults to 0.

I solved my problem by changing `child_process.exec()` to `child_process.execSync()` that differs in

> the exception that the method will not return until the child process
>   has fully closed. When a `timeout` has been encountered and `killSignal` is sent, the method won't return until the process has completely exited.

Its `timeout` option defaults to `undefined`.

Synchronous methods do block the Node.js event loop, pausing execution of any additional code until the spawned process exits.